# Frequent 503/4 errors for specific site. Site okay outside of tor

Tags: configuration, socks, error

One particular site is frequently returning 503/4 errors. If I retry often enough, 50-60 times over the period of an hour, it always eventually gets through.

There is no problem accessing the site outside of tor. I've checked with online site testers, and the site is accessible from all over the globe. The problem occurs both using socks via polipo and when using the default tor browser. It occurs when running tor from different machines in different continents.

I don't know if there is anyway I can debug this, or what it might be that is causing the problem.

Failure messages:

```
 Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT
 HTTP/1.1 504 Couldn't connect: General SOCKS server failure
 HTTP/1.1 504 Couldn't connect: SOCKS error: TTL expired
```